# the visibility points of compact set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, logic, convex-analysis

Let's the compact set has the following property:
* For every 3 points from the given set (A, B, C), exists a point from the given set (D), such that the segments AD, BD and CD are in the given set. How to prove that exist a point from the given set (A'), such that for every point (B'), the segment (A'B') is in the given set.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of context.